# Time Calculation between two latitudes and longitudes respectively?

Tags: java, android

Can we calculate time between two latitudes and longitudes without using JSON parsing  in android?

Comment: Swetha, what you mean to say is? Quite unclear question of yours.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What is the relationship between JSON and latitutes/longitude? What are you referring to?

Comment: A sample of input and expected input would go a *long* way to making this clearer...

Comment: He might be wondering how to calculate lat and long received from a geolocation API in JSON format

Comment: Time 1(in coordnate 1) - Time 2(in coordinate 2) = time requested

Answer (score 0):

You can use some webservices to query the timezone for a location. Like the ones provided by [earthtools.org](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone) to get the timezone for a particular latitude and longitude. Eg. a query to:

```
http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/40.71417/-74.00639
```

Will return the following XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<timezone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.earthtools.org/timezone.xsd">
    <version>1.1</version>
    <location>
        <latitude>40.71417</latitude>
        <longitude>-74.00639</longitude>
    </location>
    <offset>-5</offset>
    <suffix>R</suffix>
    <localtime>4 Dec 2005 12:06:56</localtime>
    <isotime>2005-12-04 12:06:56 -0500</isotime>
    <utctime>2005-12-04 17:06:56</utctime>
    <dst>False</dst>
</timezone>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get timezone of a place using Google Map's API.

Following URL may return timezone of the place which latitude is lati and longitudes is long.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/xml? location=lati,long
```

The time between two places is difference of timezones of them, so you can calculate it by following steps.

```
1. get timezone of one place by using Google Maps's API
2. get timezone of another place by using Google Maps's API
3. calculate difference of two timezones.
```